# glbinding, Qt and error "glbinding is not compatible with gl.h"

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glbinding

I'm writing a new project and want to replace GLEW with glbinding.

My setup is like this:
VS 2015, Qt 5.6, glbinding 2.0

I tried to compile quite simple code - only window (`QWindow`) with OpenGL context (`QOpenGLContext`) but got an error: *glbinding is not compatible with gl.h*

When I was tracking this bug I found out that file (which is imported by the *glbinding/gl/gl.h*) *nogl.h* is causing this message with the code below:

```
#ifdef __gl_h_
    #error "glbinding is not compatible with gl.h"
#else
    #define __gl_h_
#endif
```

Then I noticed that this is caused by the *QtGui/qopenglcontext.h* header (which I need for creating OpenGL context...). So when I don't include *qopenglcontext.h* my program compiles without error. I also noticed that this error message appears only when I include *glbinding/gl/gl.h* **after** *QtGui/qopenglcontext.h*. If I reverse the include order I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui/qopenglext.h(117): error C2065: 'GLenum': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui/qopenglext.h(117): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'mode'
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui/qopenglext.h(118): error C2065: 'GLenum': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui/qopenglext.h(118): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'target'
```

After all I still don't know how to solve this and what exactly is causing this error...

Comment: You found what's causing it: the attempt to include both headers in the same file. The `#error` is there to stop you from getting the giant error spew that you got from including them the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @NicolBolas it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*glbinding* – like practically every other OpenGL loader – has to fiddle with the OpenGL symbol tokens to avoid namespace clashing. To this end it must interact with the OpenGL definitions in a specific way, which means you must not have included any OpenGL header, or something that includes such in turn at the moment you include the *glbinding* header. The preprocessor fiddling *glbinding* performs will prevent `gl.h` getting included in a way that causes trouble.

So what you must do is: Include the *glbinding* headers in your C++ compilation unit files before everything else (Qt headers, OpenGL helper libraries and so on).